# tcsh : environment variable and pipe

Tags: pipe, tcsh

```
$ setenv a "hi"

$ echo $a
```

**hi**

Similarly, when I do the below :

```
$ setenv b "hi" | grep "hi"

$ echo $b
```

**b: Undefined variable.**

Why is the setting lost?

My actual usage is `source a.csh | grep "bla" ; echo $a (where $a is set in a.csh)`, but I thought the above is a simplistic case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page:

> If any component of a pipeline except the last is a builtin command, the pipeline is executed in a subshell.

So the variable is set in a subshell only.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out too. Should have checked man pages before asking.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `source a.csh | grep "bla" ; echo $a (where $a is set in a.csh)` the shell tries to expand the variable `$a` before actually executing the whole command so it is still not set by `source a.csh`.

Comment: The "echo $a" is actually in the next line of a long script, so it isn't actually expanded before source a.csh | grep "bla". The first part of pipe executing in the subshell answers it.